# Does it suffice to show closure only for infinitesimal transformations in a Lie group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In order to prove something forms a group, you need to (among other things) show that it is closed under group multiplication. However, for a connected Lie group, is it sufficient to show that it is closed only for infinitesimal transformations?

My logic behind this is as follows. If you have shown that the product of two infinitesimal transformations is also in the group, and any element (connected to the identity) can be written as an exponential which is simply the product of infinitely many infinitesimal transformations, then the exponential must also be in the group. The only thing making me doubt this is whether the fact that the exponential is a product of infinite infinitesimals causes problems.

For example, say you have a connected subset of a Lie group and you need to  show it is a subgroup w.r.t. the restriction of the group operation. The identity and inverse are just the identity matrix and inverse matrix so are already sorted. Thus it only remains to consider closure. An infinitesimal transformation is simply a matrix given by the identity plus an infinitesimal parameter times a generator. My question is, if you show that the product of two of these infinitesimal transformations is also in the subgroup, have you proved it for all finite transformations?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is well-posed. In order to even define "infinitesimal transformations" one already needs a group structure. It would be more clear to specify precisely what time of object (set, manifold, a set of matrices, etc.) you are starting with, and define what an "infinitesimal transformation" means for such an object.

Comment: I have added an example of what I mean.

Comment: "In order to prove something forms a group, you need to show that it is closed under group multiplication" but that is by far not sufficient in general. From your added example it seems like the set you have is given as a *subset of some other (Lie) group*, and you want to show it is a subgroup w.r.t. the restriction of the group operation. Maybe you should first of all add this assumption to the question.

Comment: Then, as you write "connected to the identity" you seem to be aware that this is highly unlikely to work unless your set is connected. So maybe add that assumption. Otherwise, even if you have an example $G$ where what you want works, apparently it will not work for $G \times $(your favourite finite discrete set), which has "the same" infinitesimal generators and yet might or might not form a group.

Comment: I've also added these assumptions to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have interpreted your question correctly but I believe the answer is no.

if you have defined some subset which is "locally closed" in the sense that things of the form $exp(X)exp(Y)$ alre also in the subset when $exp(X)$ and $exp(Y)$ are there is no guarantee that things of the form  $exp(X)exp(Y)exp(Z)$ will be too.

As a counterexample, take an actual subgroup and remove a point that cannot be written as $exp(X)$ or $exp(X)exp(Y)$.

Note that this counterexample will not work on a compact connected Lie group for example since exp is surjective there. In general exp being surjective makes the proposal true, I believe. This is quite a strong condition, however.

Comment: So you are saying that if every element can be 'reached' by the exponential (I am guessing you mean surjective rather than subjective) then it will be true? This is the case I am interested in so that's good. Is the group also being compact a requirement for this?

Comment: @Callum why is the compactness restriction necessary?

Comment: Connected and compact is not necessary. I just include it as an example of when exp is surjective. The assertion is somewhat vacuous if we assume exp is surjective since our definition of "locally closed" is then just the usual definition of closed.